# Measuring the throughput of a traffic generator

Tags: linux, networking, traffic-measurement

How could I measure the throughput of a software based traffic generator ?

Is there any tool in linux who could be of great help me to measure the exact throughput.

I am trying to measure at what rate the traffic is generated by a software generator over 1Gbps nic card.

Answer (score 0):

`netperf` is an adequate solution for measuring network throughput and latency. `iperf` is another alternative.

Comment: I am sorry but you got me wrong .. netperf is used to measure the throughput of a network. What I wanted is how do I measure at what rate a traffic generator is generating traffic

Comment: Ok, so the traffic generator is emitting traffic to some kind of sink and the sink must not be the tool measuring the throughput?

Comment: For example let us take scapy it uses a PF_PACKET socket and generates traffic .. In this case how do I measure the rate at which traffic is being generated from the machine